# How can I ignore quotechar inside field in pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas read_csv:

```
pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep=None, error_bad_lines=False, skipinitialspace=True)
```

and I've got error line:

```
Skipping line 818: ',' expected after '"'
```

One of the lines that causes an error, where quotechar inside field, but I need to ignore them:

```
..."TRANSIT CARGO VAN","T-150 148" LOW RF","...
```

If quotechar will be only around delimiter or in start or end of line, and the rest of '"' will be ignored the problem will be solved, but I do not know how.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: By default, `sep=','`, so you don't need to include that parameter

Comment: @ScottBoston I use None because some of the files has different separators `If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator`. I cant replace them, because I has also delimiters within `6,001 - 10,000` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file like this:

```
"Valid value","Another valid value","A third valid value"
"Valid value","Another valid value","A third valid value"
"Valid value", "Invalid " value","Invalid line"
"Valid value","Another valid value","A third valid value"
```

And opened it with

`print(pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None))`

And the result is:

```
             0                    1                    2
0  Valid value  Another valid value  A third valid value
1  Valid value  Another valid value  A third valid value
2  Valid value    "Invalid " value"         Invalid line
3  Valid value  Another valid value  A third valid value
```

So, pandas defaults works well in such cases.